# Cypress get siblings input and change the value?

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm new to cypress and I want to get the input field to modify the value.

I can select the row then the siblings but I can't figure out how to select the `<input ....` . On the picture below we can see the `siblings` selecting the row elements, now I want to select the input one but I can't make it:
[image]

```
<td>
  <input
   className="form-control"
   name="labelPred1"
   type="text"
   value={this.state.jsondata.prediction[k]}
   onChange={e => this.onPred1Change(k, e.target.value)}
 />
</td>


  it('modify prediction', () => {
    cy.get('table').contains('td', 'jour son facebook')
     .siblings()
     .contains('input[name=labelPred1]  ','0')
     .type('2')
  })
```

In the above code you can see the HTML structure of my input and then my Cypress test where I also tried to replace the `contains(...)` by `.get('input')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siblings takes a selector, so you could move the the input selector into it,

```js
cy.get('table')
  .contains('td', 'jour son facebook')
  .siblings('td input[name=labelPred1]')  // specify td + child input
  .type('2')
```

or maybe next td

```js
cy.get('table')
  .contains('td', 'jour son facebook')
  .next()
  .find('input[name=labelPred1]')   // within the next td
  .type('2')
```

---

This `.contains('input[name=labelPred1]','0')` doesn't work because the element is an `input` and the `'0'` isn't on the text property, it's on the value property.

`.contains()` only finds text between tags

This probably works

```js
cy.get('table')
  .contains('td', 'jour son facebook')
  .siblings()
  .find('input[name="labelPred1"][value="0"]')
  .type('2')
```